# R mlogit package: use LAPACK instead of LINPACK

Tags: r, mlogit

I am estimating a fairly simple McFadden choice model using a very large data set (101.6 million unit-alternatives). I can estimate this model just fine in Stata using the `asclogit` command, but when I try to use the `mlogit` package in R, I get the following error:

```r
region1 <- mlogit(chosen ~ mean_log.wage + mean_log.rent + bornNear + Dim.1 + regionFE | 0,
                  shape= "long", chid.var = "chid", alt.var = "alternatives", data = ready)

Error in qr.default(na.omit(X)) : too large a matrix for LINPACK
Calls: mlogit ... model.matrix -> model.matrix.mFormula -> qr -> qr.default
```

If I look at the [source code](https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/base/R/qr.R) of `qr.R` it's clear that the number of elements in my design matrix is too big relative to the `LINPACK` limit of 2,147,483,647. However, no such limit exists for `LAPACK` (that I can tell, at least).

From `qr.R`:

```r
qr.default <- function(x, tol = 1e-07, LAPACK = FALSE, ...)
{
    x <- as.matrix(x)
    if(is.complex(x))
        return(structure(.Internal(La_qr_cmplx(x)), class = "qr"))
    ## otherwise :
    if(LAPACK)
        return(structure(.Internal(La_qr(x)), useLAPACK = TRUE, class = "qr"))
    ## else "Linpack" case:
    p <- as.integer(ncol(x))
    if(is.na(p)) stop("invalid ncol(x)")
    n <- as.integer(nrow(x))
    if(is.na(n)) stop("invalid nrow(x)")
    if(1.0 * n * p > 2147483647) stop("too large a matrix for LINPACK")
    ...
```

`qr()` appears to be called in the `mFormula` method of `mlogit`, when `model.matrix` is being created, and probably while [checking NAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452801/fitting-a-linear-mixed-model-to-a-very-large-data-set). But I can't tell if there is a way to pass `LAPACK = TRUE` to `mlogit`, or if there is a way to skip the NA checking.

I'm hoping [@YvesCroissant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10273251/yves-croissant) will see this.

As I mentioned, I can estimate this model just fine in Stata, so it's not a question of resources. My Stata license is not portable, however, which is why I would like to use R.

Comment: I suppose you meant passing `LAPACK = TRUE`. A little hard to help without being able to reproduce the issue (could we simply generate lots of data for that?). Couple of things: 1) you may want to look into the RStata package allowing to get Stata's output to R, 2) you could define your own function, identical to `mlogit:::model.matrix.mFormula` except for the `qr(na.omit(X))` call at the end, where you could add `LAPACK = TRUE`, and then `assignInNamespace("model.matrix.mFormula", myfun, ns = "mlogit")` should override it.

Comment: @JuliusVainora I had also thought to hard-code in `LAPACK = TRUE` in the appropriate place, but wasn't sure where to start with that. Your comment is helpful! Not sure if it would be useful to generate lots of data to reproduce this problem, since not many people have access to 50+GB of RAM, which is what it would take. I may come up with something and edit my post, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Julius' comment and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279904/modifying-an-r-package-function-for-current-r-session-assigninnamespace-not-beh) on namespaces in R, I figured out the answer. I added the following code right after my library statements:

```r
source("mymFormula.R")
tmpfun <- get("model.matrix.mFormula", envir = asNamespace("mlogit"))
environment(mymFormula) <- environment(tmpfun)
attributes(mymFormula) <- attributes(tmpfun)  # don't know if this is really needed
assignInNamespace("model.matrix.mFormula", mymFormula, ns="mlogit")
```

`mymFormula.R` is an R script where I copy/pasted the contents of `mlogit:::model.matrix.mFormula` and added `mymFormula <-` before the `function` invocation at the top of the file.

I viewed the contents of `mlogit:::model.matrix.mFormula` by typing `trace(mlogit:::model.matrix.mFormula, edit=TRUE)` in RStudio. (Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466063/how-can-i-edit-the-source-code-for-an-r-function) for help on how to do that.)